# Who is the Ever Min HeChai?

Tags: jewish-books, authorship

I saw a few commentaries in two source sheets at Sefaria attributed to a book called "Ever Min HeChai." The commentaries were on Sefer Bereshit.

Anyone know who this is? An internet search did not yield anything except the mitzvah. Thanks and shanah tovah.

Comment: Where did you see this? Please [edit] to include more details.

Answer (score 5):

Somehow I never saw this question before now. In the future if you have questions like this about content on Sefaria you can email hello[at]sefaria[dot]org or the [Sefaria User forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/sefaria) - I obviously can't guarantee anything but answers there usually take less than a year (which is apparently how long it takes to get an answer here :-)).

Ever Min Hachai was/is a new commentary being written by someone who wished to remain anonymous. They were looking for somewhere to put it, and thought Sefaria was the right place to do it. After some conversations between the poster and Sefaria, a mutual decision was reached that Sefaria was not the right place (at that time) for the commentary and it was removed.

As Sefaria builds capability to support modern works, it may return, hopefully with some explanation of it's origins and authorship.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [this *kuntress*](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=31929&pgnum=1) titled "הלכות חלה והלכות אבר מן החי" is the work in question?